# how to add a new field if a option from combobox is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

So , I'm trying to create a login form using windows forms and I have the username/password fields and another one where you can select a value from combobox. I want to add a new field is a specific value is selected from combobox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructing forms on the fly is rather bad, especially when you know all the fields you will require upfront anyway. It results in a lot of code that deals with creating the UI, which is hard to read and to maintain. A good approach to solve this is putting all the fields you may need in a panel and hide this panel. When the right combobox item is selected, simply show the panel.

[image]

```
    private void cbxOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlFurtherOptions.Visible = (cbxOptions.SelectedIndex == 1);
    }
```

If you need different panels for different combobox selections, you can realise that by putting the panels in a FlowLayoutPanel and only show the ones you need. Doing it this way, you can use the Designer to construct the forms (and have all the UI code where it should be). Furthermore, you can maintain the UI in the Designer as well.